# One line to define a specific property for all named datasources in Quarkus application.properties

Tags: datasource, quarkus, properties-file

I'm wondering if there is a way to define a property for multiple named datasources in one line?

For example, instead of doing this

```
quarkus.datasource."name1".db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource."name2".db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource."name3".db-kind=postgresql
```

I want to do something like this in one line for "name1", "name2", "name3"

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
```

But this won't work however since `quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql` will be assigned to the default datasource and not "name1", "name2", "name3", etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this, you need to specify the names of each datasource explicitly.

The reason is that each name maps to multiple properties, not the other way around

Comment: I see. I wish there was since the properties file quickly fills up when you have many datasources.

Comment: You can always open an issue asking for this feature :)